# Анимация зачеркивания слова при наведении

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-animation

Я пытаюсь сделать  **анимацию зачеркивания**, как показан этот эффект на изображении ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Линия зачеркивания появляется слева направо и исчезает тоже слева направо.

```css
@keyframes strike {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

.strike {
  position: relative;
}

.strike:hover:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  animation-name: strike;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: fill;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  The text in the span <span class="strike">is what I want to strike out</span>.
</div>
```

Есть ли способ достичь этого только с помощью CSS?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Strike in and out animation on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44633600/7394871) от участника  [@sonia maklouf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6485567/sonia-maklouf).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44633600/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать `transforms` и `transform-origin` в анимации ключевых кадров, чтобы сделать
 **анимацию появления линии зачеркивания  слева направо и исчезновение линии тоже слева направо.**

Задача состоит в том, чтобы масштабировать псевдоэлемент по оси `X` от 0 до 1 с началом преобразования слева и затем обратно до `0` с началом преобразования справа (аналогично [этому эффекту наведения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28623513/7394871) см. Последний пример ответа).

А вот пример с вашей разметкой:

```css
@keyframes strike{
  0%     { transform-origin:  0% 50%;transform:scaleX(0); }
  50%    { transform-origin:  0% 50%;transform:scaleX(1);  }
  50.01% { transform-origin:100% 50%;transform:scaleX(1);  }
  100%   { transform-origin:100% 50%;transform:scaleX(0);  }
}
.strike {
  position: relative;
}
.strike:hover:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  animation: strike .75s ease-in-out forwards;
}
```

```html
<div>
    The text in the span <span class="strike">is what I want to strike out</span>.
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Strike in and out animation on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44633730/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример с использованием `transition`, где он применяется  при наведении курсора влево / вправо.

```css
.strike {
  position: relative;
}
.strike::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}
.strike:hover::after {
  right: 0;
  left: 100%;
  transition: right .5s .0s, left .5s .5s;  
}
```

```html
<div>
  The text in the span <span class="strike">is what I want to strike out</span>.
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Strike in and out animation on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44635407/7394871) от участника  [@LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson).</sub>